# Async Tcp Server I just can get one client

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp

Async Tcp Server I just can get one client.

When I have more than one client.I just get first client in server,but others client connected in client.

Here is my server code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace BeginAcceptTcpClientserver
{

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(1234);
        listener.Start();
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(callbake,listenner);

        Console.WriteLine("print q to quit");
        ConsoleKey key;
        do 
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
        } while (key != ConsoleKey.Q);

    }
    static void callbake(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        TcpClient clienter = ((TcpListener)ar.AsyncState).EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("---client connect {0}<--{1} ---", clienter.Client.LocalEndPoint, clienter.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient only listens for one incoming connection. You need to call it again and again, perhaps in your callback method:

```
static void callbake(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // call BeginAcceptTcpClient here so that it's called everytime a connection is accepted
    TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;
    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(callbake), listener);

    TcpClient clienter = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
    Console.WriteLine("---client connect {0}<--{1} ---", clienter.Client.LocalEndPoint, clienter.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
}
```